# How to use an element in a list as a condition in ifelse

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a list with multiple conditional statements as each element.  I want to use each element in the list as a conditional statement, specifically in an ifelse statement.  I've tried different combinations of noquote, paste, etc. and still only receive NA as a returned value.  Here is some test data:

```
#Set these equal to some number to test the ifelse statement
B11 <- 0.1
B15 <- 0.03
#Create a list of conditions
l <- list("B11 >= -0.012 & B15 >=  0.030")
#Somehow evaluate the condition within an ifelse statement
ifelse(l[[1]], "yes", "no")
#This should return "yes" but always returns NA
```

Comment: Remove quotes...to this `list(B11 >= -0.012 & B15 >=  0.030)`

Comment: If you really want to give the conditions as a string, you have to tell `R` that this string should be evaluated as a command in `R`, which is possbile via `eval(parse(text=l[[1]]))` which gives `TRUE`, hence do `ifelse(eval(parse(text=l[[1]])), "yes", "no")`

Comment: @Jonas That solves the problem directly.  The conditions aren't typed in... they are a result of other functions.  Thank you for your answer.  If you submit as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I submitted it again as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the condition given as a string, you have to tell `R` that the string is not simply a string, but rather a command. To tell `R` that the string is a command, use `eval(parse(text=...))`.

In your case

```
ifelse(eval(parse(text=l[[1]])), "yes", "no")
```

But you have to make sure that there is no malicious command given in the string when evaluating it, like `eval(parse(text="q('no')"))`. The function `q` quits your current `R`session and the argument `no` stands for not saving the current workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You created the list using your condition like string, not like a condition. To work what you want, you have to remove double quote, like this:

```
l <- list(B11 >= -0.012 & B15 >=  0.030)

ifelse(l[[1]], "yes", "no")
```

Output:

```
[1] "yes
```

Hope was helpful.